# How to hit a URL through ajax in the script of a chrome extension? The url has variables also

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to hit a URL with a web service already written for it. I have ajax in my script, but the url changes with the variables. I am not able to access it.

The script file is this:

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

$("#save").click(function(){
  window.location.href="save.html " ;

});




$("#save_tags").click(function(){

 chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
   var  curl = tabs[0].url;   
//keep this filled and try to use post method on url
var tags=$("input").val();
var url="http://166.62.18.107:8080/PumpAppWebsevice/REST/webService/addLinkPumpApp;userID=1;linkURL="+curl+";tags="+tags+";";
//alert(url);
  var jxhr= $.ajax({ 
    type:'GET',
    url:url,
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
      console.log("oh no!");
    }
});

});
window.location.href="save_tags.html";
});




});
```

Comment: I've answered your question, but I also downvoted it. Please read through [ask] to understand how to write better questions. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Tldr post console output. Use https. Post manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to URL-encode your `curl`/`tags` parameters using `encodeURIComponent`.

Consider:

```
var curl = "http://example.com/test?parameter1&parameter2";
var tags = "???";
var badurl = "http://your.rest.service/PumpAppWebsevice/REST/webService/addLinkPumpApp;userID=1;linkURL="
  +curl+";tags="+tags+";";
var goodurl = "http://your.rest.service/PumpAppWebsevice/REST/webService/addLinkPumpApp;userID=1;linkURL="
  +encodeURIComponent(curl)+";tags="+encodeURIComponent(tags)+";";
console.log(badurl);
console.log(goodurl);
```

Will give:

```
http://your.rest.service/PumpAppWebsevice/REST/webService/addLinkPumpApp;userID=1;linkURL=http://example.com/test?parameter1&parameter2;tags=???;
http://your.rest.service/PumpAppWebsevice/REST/webService/addLinkPumpApp;userID=1;linkURL=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%3Fparameter1%26parameter2;tags=%3F%3F%3F
```

The first URL is malformed, the second actually responds with success (if actual service IP is used).